# How to toggle between two nested partial forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

So the user chose "Run" as his `challenge`. Now he should be able to toggle between the categories: `oneshot` or `ongoing`.

Right now all the attributes are showing, but how can I only show the `oneshot` attribute `:deadline` if the user clicks "One-shot" and how can I only show the `ongoing` attributes if the user clicks "Ongoing"?

[image]

**challenges/_form.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for(@challenge) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :action %>
    <% Challenge::CATEGORY.each do |c| %>
      <%= label(c, c) %>:
      <%= f.radio_button(:category, c, :class => "date-format-switcher") %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.fields_for :category do |category| %>
      <%= render 'category_fields', :f => category %>
    <% end %>
    <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn")  do %>
      Save
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

**challenges/_category_fields.html.erb**

```
  One-Shot
    <%= f.date_select :deadline, :order => [:month, :day, :year], use_short_month: true, class: 'date-select' %>
  Ongoing
    <%= f.date_select :date_started, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :with_css_classes => true, :class => "date-select" %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :committed, Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s %>
    <%= f.number_field :days_challenged, value: 30, class: 'day-challenge' %> 
    <script>
      $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
      })
    </script>
```

**challenge.rb**

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :oneshot,  -> { where(categories: 'One-Shot') }
    scope :ongoing,  -> { where(categories: 'Ongoing') }
    CATEGORY = ['One-Shot', 'Ongoing']
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each partial form in a div with an id and add some javascript on the radio_button clicks.

```
$(function(){
  $('#id_of_first_radio').click(function(){ $('#id_of_first_div').show(); $('#id_of_second_div').hide(); });
  $('#id_of_second_radio').click(function(){ $('#id_of_first_div').hide(); $('#id_of_second_div').show(); });
});
```

Comment: There is one partial form: challenges/_category_fields.html.erb. Are you suggesting I make another partial form or should I wrap "One-Shot" and "Ongoing" in the form with something? Thanks for your help sir.

Comment: The latter. I'm suggesting you add <div id='id_of_first_div'> around the one-shot header and form elements. And <div id='id_of_second_div'> around the ongoing header and form elements. With container divs around the two sections you can toggle their visibility with javascript.